# Connecting with 3 different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have to connect with 3 diferent databases. How can i do that? I'm working on web application in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: are you able to connect in one database? If yes, add two more connectionstrings, and then replicate the same procedure you've done to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that, you have to go to your web.config file and write this.

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="First" connectionString="..."/>
<add name="Second" connectoinString="..."/>
<add name="Third" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You have to change the name of each connection and the connectionString too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use 3 different databases at same time for different things, then you must have 3 different connections string.

But if you want change by 3 different databases one at a time, then you must have something like data access layer classes/namespaces.

Or use a generic data provider, like ODBC / OleDB connection.

I hope it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are all located on the same data source, then you set your connection string to point to [master] as the initial catalog.  You can then do queries like:

```
select * from [database].[schema].[table]
```

This, however is NOT ideal.  What you should be doing is have three separate connection strings in your web.config to each database and create **SqlConnection** objects to each when needed, perhaps use something along the lines of a [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

If your databases are hosted on separate data sources, and you don't want multiple connection strings in your web.config then you can look at [linked servers](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3085211/Linked-Servers-on-MS-SQL-Part-1.htm).